# How do I format the Y axis to show 2000 instead of 2 with a label of MyLabel(10^3)?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Using ZedGraph, how do I format the Y axis to show 2000 instead of 2 with a label of MyLabel(10^3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the scale's [Format Property](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_Scale_Format.htm) to, say, "#" and the [Mag Property](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_Scale_Mag.htm) to zero. For example:

```
 YAxis y = myPane.YAxis;
 y.Scale.Format = "#";
 y.Scale.Mag = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [MagAuto](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_Scale_MagAuto.htm) property to false:

```
zedGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.MagAuto = false;
```

Note that clicking on "Set Scale to Default" in the ZedGraph context menu will reset `MagAuto` to `true`. This is the source of a part of the context menu event handler:

```
public void ResetAutoScale( GraphPane pane, Graphics g )
{
    _scale._minAuto = true;
    _scale._maxAuto = true;
    _scale._majorStepAuto = true;
    _scale._minorStepAuto = true;
    _crossAuto = true;
    _scale._magAuto = true;
    //this.numDecAuto = true;
    _scale._formatAuto = true;
    pane.AxisChange( g );
}
```

Comment: Why answer an already answered question which is 5 years old ?

Comment: @Thomas: I was looking how to do that myself, found this question, tested the answer provided by Jim Fred, and noticed that there was a simpler way. Figured that somebody else could benefit from my answer...